# Does it help if proofs are orthogonal?

Tags: idris, proof-of-correctness

Suppose I have a function

```
f : Vect m Nat -> Vect n Nat -> {auto _ : Proof m n} -> Foo m n
```

where

```
data Proof : Nat -> Nat -> Type where
  Eq : Proof x x
  One : Proof 1 _
```

I can make a `Proof 1 1` as `Eq` or `One`. Thus these aren't "orthogonal". In more complicated examples, I can have recursive data constructors where I might be able to provide a proof as `Constructor1 Constructor2` or `Constructor3 Constructor1`. Does it matter if constructors aren't orthogonal? In particular, does it hinder proof search?

Comment: Regarding tags, you should only tag more than one language if your question is about comparing or translating between those specific languages. For non-language-specific questions, you can use the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal data constructors make it simpler and clearer to implement functions. With overlapping constructors, you will be duplicating behaviour between patterns e.g.

```
foo : Proof x y -> ?
foo Eq = ?eq
foo One = ?one  -- duplicates `foo (Eq {x = 1})`
```